# How will bash evaluate following code

Tags: bash, exit

This question has two parts:

(a) Understanding what the code snipped is doing

(b) Understanding the difference between *exit status* and *return status* in context of `bash`.

Here is the code snipped I am trying to understand:

```
if var=-2 && (( var+=2 ))
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

Running this produces `False`. I cannot understand why this is happening.

If I understand this correctly here is what maybe happening with the `if` condition:

(a) `var=-2` creates exit status of 0, because the assignment is a success

(b) `(( var+=2 ))` adds 2 to the value of `var` and the expression evaluates zero. So the exit status is 1 for this term

(c) 0 && 1 creates an exist status of 0 which is then used by `if` construct

The `if` construct is supposed to simply check the exit status and when it is zero it takes the *then* path. In step (c) above it is zero but the script still takes the *else* path. Is this correct way to understand this?

Also, I keep seeing various `bash` texts use *exit status* and *return status* interchangeably.

I doubt `var=-2` assignment would have any kind of exit status because it is not a program. But any clarification on the difference between two will be great.

Comment: run it with `#!/bin/bash -x` to see what it is happening

Comment: + var=-2
    + ((  var+= 2  ))
    + echo 'False path is evaluated'
This does not help me understand the exit status/return status being seen by the if construct. The point is understanding the construct, not to be cryptic.

Comment: from `man bash`: **expression1 && expression2**
                     True if both expression1 and expression2 are true.
              **expression1 || expression2**
                     True if either expression1 or expression2 is true.

              The **&&** and **||** operators do not evaluate expression2 if the value
              of  expression1  is  sufficient to determine the return value of
              the entire conditional expression.

Comment: Your misunderstanding seems to be in (c), specifically "0 && 1 creates an exist status of 0." `0 && 1`, in fact, is `1`.

Comment: This is for the exact same reason `i=0; ((i++))` has a failed exit status, whereas `i=0; ((++i))` has a successful one. **Inside an arithmetic context, positive integers are truthy and zero is falsey.**

Answer (score 10):

That's:

```
if
  first list of commands
then
  second list of commands
else
  third list of commands
fi
```

That's to run the second list of commands if the first list of commands returns with a *true*/*success* (zero) exit status, that is if the last run command in there returns with a zero exit status.

In:

```
var=-2 && ((var += 2))
```

It's `cmd1 && cmd2` where `cmd2` is only run if `cmd1` is successful.

```
var=-2
```

Will typically be successful as long as `$var` has not been made read-only, so the `((var += 2))` command will be run:

```
((arithmetic expression))
```

Returns *success*/*true* as long as the expression is correctly evaluated (no syntax error) and the result of the expression is non-zero.

- `((123))`, `((1 + 1))`, `((1 == 1))` return true
- `((0))`, `((-2 + 2))`, `((2 == -2))` return false.
- `((4294967296 * 4294967296))` <sub>return false in most shells because of 64 bit integer wrapping</sub>

`var += 2` as an arithmetic expression, performs the assignment and resolves to the value being assigned, here 0, hence the *false* exit status.

You can see the value upon which is based the exit status, by using the `$((...))` arithmetic expansion syntax:

```
$ echo "$((1 + 1)) $((2 == 2)) $((2 == -2)) $((var = -2)) $((var += 2))"
2 1 0 -2 0
```

Or assigning it to a variable:

```
$ var=-2; ((result = (var += 2)))
$ echo "$? $result $var"
1 0 0
```

`$?` contains the exit status of the previous command. As far as `if`/`then`/`else`/`fi` is concerned, 0 means true, anything else means false.

The confusion here comes from the fact that for arithmetic expressions, it's the other way round: `0` means false and anything else means true (for instance, `2 == 2` is `1` while `2 < 1` is `0`).

To avoid worrying about the difference, just forget about `$?` and its possible values. Just think in terms of boolean *true*/*false*, *sucess*/*failure*.

```
 grep -q foo file
```

Returns true if `foo` is found in `file`.

```
 [ "$a" = "$b" ]
```

Returns true if `$a` contains the same thing as `$b`.

```
 ((6 * 3 - 12))
 ((4 == 1))
```

Return true if the result of the arithmetic expression is a non-zero number.

It doesn't matter whether those *true*/*false* are expressed in terms of 0 or 1 of the exit status of those `grep`/`[` commands or `((...))` construct.

Comment: You are mistaken here: "The confusion here comes from the fact that for arithmetic expressions, it's the other way round: 0 means false and anything else means true (for instance, 2 == 2 is 1 while 2 > 1 is 0)." I have run this examples and got: `((2==2)); echo $? output 0
((2 > 1)); echo $? output 0`

Comment: @MiniMax, you're missing my point. The `2==2` arithmetic expression results in `1` (see `echo "$((2==2))"`), because it's not 0, the `((...))` construct returns _true_ (it returns a 0 exit status, but as I said you generally don't need to worry about which exit code means true or false)

Comment: Now I understand your point. But  why 2 > 1 is false, anyway? $((2 > 1)) is return 0, yes, therefore is false according your logic. In here "0 means false and anything else means true (for instance, 2 == 2 is 1 while 2 > 1 is 0)". I can't understand this sentence.

Comment: Wow, $((2 > 1)) results 1. :) Checked it now.

Comment: @MiniMax sorry that was a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

> (c) 0 && 1 creates an exist status of 0 which is then used by `if` construct

There's the mistake. 0 && 1 results in `1`. This isn't C or Java, remember. In the shell 0 && 1 is what you'd get from `true && false`.

```
$ true; echo $?
0
$ false; echo $?
1
$ true && false; echo $?
1
```

> Also, I keep seeing various bash texts use exit status and return status interchangeably.

They are interchangeable. What you want to keep in mind is that `0` indicates success and non-`0` indicates failure. It's the opposite of most programming languages where `0` is false and `1` is true.

Comment: Good answer insofar as it goes, but the distinction between arithmetic value and exit status is important and doesn't appear to be explicitly defined. I'm not sure that the OP understands *why* an arithmetic operation with a result of `0` is different from a command with an exit status of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working as expected .

```
if var=-2 && (( var+=2 ))
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

**Code explaination :-**

`if var=-2 && (( var+=2 ))`

`var=-2 => true`     Value is non-zero so evaluated as true

`var+=2 => false`    Value is zero so evaluated as false

this is like

`if true && false`

As per logical computation **true && false => false**

In that case here is our final code

```
if (false)
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

Comment: `var=0`, `var=-2` evaluate to true. The value of the assigment doesn't matter here. `var=1$(false)` would return false. `((var=0))` would return false, `((var=1$(false)))` would return true.